# how to generate fractals from audio output?

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio

How to generate fractal video/image from the audio output

I have tried with `flam3 | pulseaudio | alsa-sink-ALC25`

without succes

Comment: (1) Use `parecord` on the `.monitor` source that corresponds to your audio output to get raw audio data. (2) According to the [readme](http://flam3.com/README.txt), `flam3` needs parameter files in a specific format. How do you intend to convert the raw audio into these parameter files? (3) I am not aware of any ready-made software that somehow turns audio into flame pictures, you may have to write or own or modify existing ones like `flam3`.

Comment: (1) I do not know about `parecord` that sounds interesting, thanks. (2) Yes the readme does not provide things like this, that is why I have tried to pipe it. (3) from memory some software are able to use the sound to make the wave react, and yes, that type of software should certainly convert something from the stream to the video.

Comment: So how exactly do you expect to pipe random data to produce a parameter file in some required format? That makes no sense.

Comment: To make it clear, I would like to produce fractal in a terminal depending of the sound coming from a website. Pipe is certainly not the correct way to make it, but I have tried.

Comment: Yes, I understood that this is what you want. However, `flam3` requires initial parameters like in [test.flam3](https://github.com/scottdraves/flam3/blob/master/test.flam3), that is, `<flame>` tags with a bunch of coefficients. These are one-time start parameters, from which a series of images is generated. Even if you take audio data and use it somehow to generate the initial coefficients (which you didn't), you'd still just generate a flame sequence from maybe a millisecond of initial audio, which is *not* what you want. So you need a different software.